# Not able to connect through RDP to a azure VM after trying to set static IP on BOX

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am not able to connect through RDP to a azure VM after i tried to set static IP on box's adapter setting.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/detailed-troubleshoot-rdp and report more information in your question on steps you have tried.

Also you may want to check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection